# SalesforceIQ: How to get all contact objects?

Tags: python, salesforce

I'm using SalesforceIQ and am trying to get all contact objects.  The API docs indicate how to do this if I have their IDs (just supply an array of IDs when using Contact().fetchByIDs(...)).

They don't indicate how to do it if I don't have IDs.

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you look carefully at the documentation, you see that IDs array is an optional parameter - [Get All Contacts](https://api.salesforceiq.com/#/python#documentation_contacts_get-all-contacts). Also don't forget, that Salesforce returns contacts in batches (see *limit* parameter) and you need to execute multiple calls using *start* parameter.